# onOptionsItemSelected method can it have 3 items?

Tags: android

I am using Android Studio and I was wondering is there a possibility to have in a `"onOptionsItemSelected"` method more then 2 items? If so how? Thanks in advance.

BTW I have tried just adding another case which gives a problem

```
case R.id.DropDB:{
        AlertDialog.Builder builder4 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
        builder4.setTitle("DeleteMassage")
        builder4.setPositiveButton("set", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    msgsDB.DeleteTable();

                }
                });
            return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can put as many items as you want.
You have to do several thing. First, you have to create an xml that you will put in the folder : res/menu, for example you can name it myMenu.xml

In this xml, you vreate the menu with all yours items

**myMenu.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_1" android:title="@string/action_1" android:icon="@drawable/action_1" android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item android:id="@+id/action_2" android:title="@string/action_2" android:orderInCategory="100" android:showAsAction="never" />
    <item android:id="@+id/action_3" android:title="@string/action_3" android:orderInCategory="100" android:showAsAction="never" />
    <item android:id="@+id/action_4" android:title="@string/action_4" android:orderInCategory="100" android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

After in your main-Activity, you need to specify your menu :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.myMenu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

and then you can implement all the case you need in order to put you action :

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item) {

    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.action_1:
            //You code for the action1
            return true;

        case R.id.action_2:
            //You code for the action2
            return true;

        case R.id.action_3:
            //You code for the action3
            return true;

        case R.id.action_4:
            //You code for the action4
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```